# Does Windows 7 support multiple mouse drivers being installed?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse

I use a laptop for work that plugs into a docking station to which my Logitec G5 mouse is connected.  I often take my laptop home where I will connect my Logitech G500.  To my understanding, these two mice use the same drivers, so there shouldn't be any conflicts.  However, I am thinking of buying a non-Logitech mouse for work.  I'd like to know that the non-Logitech drivers will work for the non-Logitech mouse while my Logitech drivers will work for my G500 when I take my laptop home.

Comment: You can install as many mouse drivers as you like. Windows will always use the driver for the device that is actually connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install an unlimited amount of drivers (mouse or otherwise). In reality though, nearly all mice use the same standard mouse driver provided by Microsoft.

Comment: But if it's a specialized mouse with 4 additional buttons in excess of the standard 3, wouldn't I need the drivier specifically for that mouse?  Do mouse drivers use the mouse-specific driver as well as Windows's underlying drivers?  How does that work?

Comment: For every device, Windows uses the best matching driver. Your special mouse can probably function with Microsoft's default driver, but those extra buttons might not function. When you install the special driver, Windows will use that instead.